# picture formatting for kernel svm

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I'm having some difficulty to get a series of images into the correct format to feed into sklearn.svm.SVC.

This is my first image recognition project, and so Im suffering a bit.

Ive got a loop which brings in a bunch of base64 RGB images (of different sizes) to a dataframe

```
imageData = mpimg.imread(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(value)),format='JPG')
```

then I convert the RGB image into gray-scale, and flatten

```
data_images = rgb2gray(imageData).ravel()
```

where rgb2gray:

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    r, g, b = rgb[:,:,0], rgb[:,:,1], rgb[:,:,2]
    gray = 0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b
    return gray
```

If I look at the size differences

```
df_raw.sample(10)
```

[image]

We can see that the picture pixel lengths are not the same between my samples. Im a little confused here about how to proceed. For lack of a better idea I decided to add a padding based on the picture with the largest size,

```
df_raw.picLen.max()
```

Then appending a number of zeros to the end of each 1D picture array.

```
def padPic(x,numb,maxN):
    N = maxN-len(x)
    out = np.pad(x,(numb,N),'constant')
    return out
```

calling

```
df_raw['picNew'] = df_raw.apply(lambda row: padPic(row['pic'],0,df_raw.picLen.max()), axis=1)
df_raw['picNewLen']  = df_raw.apply(lambda row: len(row['picNew']), axis=1)
```

I now have arrays all of the same size
[image]

From here I attempt to fit a model to support vector algorithm using the picture data as X and a set of labels as y.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_raw.picNew, df_raw.name, test_size = 0.2, random_state=42)
```

check the size:

```
print('Training data and target sizes: \n{}, {}'.format(X_train.shape,y_train.shape))
print('Test data and target sizes: \n{}, {}'.format(X_test.shape,y_test.shape))
```

> Training data and target sizes:  (198,), (198,) Test data and target
>   sizes:  (50,), (50,)

after Ive convinced myself everything is ready, then I try to fit the model

```
svm = SVC()
svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

this throws an error, and I cant figure out why:

> /opt/wakari/anaconda/envs/ulabenv_2018-11-13_10.15.00/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
>       499 
>       500     """
>   --> 501     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>       502 
>       503
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I think this must have to do with the array size, but I cant figure it out. :-/

In addition to the error, more generally, I have a question to my approach in general. In particular I think my "padding" is probably incorrect and maybe some resize would be better.
I appreciate any feedback to my methodology. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive figured out the problem.

Thank you to Artem for his catching my obvious problem of not encoding the classes, but this was not my issue in the end.

Turns out the way that my picture array was represented was incorrect. 
The original array was `df_raw['picNew'].shape` which evaluates to

> (248,)

What I needed was a 2D representation

```
np.stack(df_raw['picNew'] , axis=1).shape
```

> (830435, 248)

All good now.

I'm still unsure about the most "correct" way to resize the images to be all the same length. Appending 0 to the array lengths seems a bit unsophisticated... So if anyone has an idea :)

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is due to using list in a feature column and strings as target values. For the latter You need to use `LabelEncoder` class to turn them to normalized class labels, as required by fit().

See description here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

This needs to be done before train/test split to make sure you have all names 'seen' by the LabelEncoder.

For the former, you might want to search for MNIST tutorials, that will provide a plethora of algorightms applied to image classification problems.

Also, Resize before flattening should work better than padding.

Comment: shoot, I completely missed the encoder. Thank you. When I fit and set the encoder le = LabelEncoder(), le.fit(df_raw.name), le.transform(df_raw.name) I still have the same error.

Comment: just to show that my pictures have an equal amount of elements. 'result = map(lambda x: len(x), X_train), print(np.unique(list(result))) ' [830435]